# redux-form: REGISTER_FIELD / UNREGISTER_FIELD get called after change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Sample 1 is working but when put `Field` in another component then returning it is not working. Is is triggering `UNREGISTER_FIELD` event.

Sample 1(working):

```
const HeroFormField = () => {
  return <Field
      component={InputField}
      name={'name'}
    />
}
```

Sample 2(not working):

```
const HeroFormField = () => {

  const CustomField = () => <Field
      component={InputField}
      name={'name'}
    />;
   
   return <CustomField />;

  // I need to do this
  //return <SomeComposableComponent title={<CustomField />}  />;
}
```

Comment: I tried your example and it worked without any problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-simple-example-forked-jhwc5?file=/SimpleForm.js.

Comment: Thanks @SoufianeBoutahlil. I think I found the issue. Probably redux selector issue.